# HTML: changing image onclick?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, colors

I have two html codes: one is a table with black images and the other one is the same table but the only difference is that the images are orange (but the only thing that changes is the color).

When I click on a black image , I'd like it to be orange and stay orange. Please, how can I do this?

This is the part of my code where the black images are (Alarm.jpg, Alarm-17.jpg, and the other Alarm are the buttons):

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="Alarm.jpg" width="153" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="Alarm-17.jpg" width="142" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="Alarm-18.jpg" width="141" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="Alarm-19.jpg" width="161" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="espacio.gif" width="1" height="159" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

And this is the part of my other code where the orange images are:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="AlarmOrange.jpg" width="153" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="AlarmOrange-17.jpg" width="142" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="AlarmOrange-18.jpg" width="141" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="AlarmOrange-19.jpg" width="161" height="159" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="espacio.gif" width="1" height="159" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

I guess it's something like when I click on a black image it should change the picture to the picture of the orange image but i don't know how to do this.

I DONT KNOW MUCH ABOUT HTML, CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME?

Comment: those are in fact images and not buttons.

Comment: I updated it, thanks, yes, they are images. When i click on a black image i'd like it to be an orange image and stay orange

Comment: And you are changing images not colors :) And you need javascript or jQuery for this :)

Comment: And what should I use @BojanPetkovski ? Can you show me a link or sth where I can learn about how to do this please?

Comment: Are the images the same, and just the background is orange? Then make the images transparent and just change the background color from black to orange :)

Comment: google image flips there's  a hundred ways to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an event handler to your `<img>` elements such that when they are clicked, a JavaScript function is called that replaces the "src" attribute resulting in a replaced image.

Here is some sample HTML

```
<img width="128" height="128"
src="http://www.neilkolban.com/stackexchange/images/greenButton.png"
onclick="changeColor(event);" />
```

And some sample JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(event) {
    $(event.target).attr("src", "http://www.neilkolban.com/stackexchange/images/redButton.png");
}
```

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/cumozt4p/) is also available.

(Changed to "event.target" from "event.srcElement" as suggested by comment poster).

The jQuery plugin will also need to be loaded for this to work.

Comment: Your code only works in IE. srcElement is only available in IE. In all other browsers it is target :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Oooh ... I don't disagree with you, but I built and ran this on Chrome ... so it looks like Chrome has this attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 $('.imagewrapper').on('click', 'img.black', function(){
  $(this).next('img.orange').fadeIn();
 });
 $('.imagewrapper').on('click', 'img.orange', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).fadeOut();
 });
});
```

```css
.imagewrapper{
 position: relative;
}
img.black{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: black;
}
img.orange{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: orange;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <div class="imagewrapper">
          <img src="Alarm.jpg" width="153" height="159" alt="" class="black">
          <img src="AlarmOrange.jpg" width="153" height="159" alt="" class="orange">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="imagewrapper">
          <img src="Alarm-17.jpg" width="142" height="159" alt="" class="black">
          <img src="AlarmOrange-17.jpg" width="142" height="159" alt="" class="orange">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="imagewrapper">
          <img src="Alarm-18.jpg" width="141" height="159" alt="" class="black">
          <img src="AlarmOrange-18.jpg" width="141" height="159" alt="" class="orange">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td colspan="3">
      <div class="imagewrapper">
          <img src="Alarm-19.jpg" width="161" height="159" alt="" class="black">
          <img src="AlarmOrange-19.jpg" width="161" height="159" alt="" class="orange">
      </div>
     </td>
     <td>
         <img src="espacio.gif" width="1" height="159" alt="">
     </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for a pure CSS solution.  I am changing the `background-color`, but you can change the `background-image` instead to your images.

```css
.target {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
.hidden-target {
  display: none;
}
.hidden-target:checked + .target {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="hidden-flag1" type="radio" class="hidden-target">
      <label for="hidden-flag1" class="target">Click</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="hidden-flag2" type="radio" class="hidden-target">
      <label for="hidden-flag2" class="target">Click</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="hidden-flag3" type="radio" class="hidden-target">
      <label for="hidden-flag3" class="target">Click</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="hidden-flag4" type="radio" class="hidden-target">
      <label for="hidden-flag4" class="target">Click</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```